# WPF C# Programmatically adding Styles from Resource Dictionary?

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, resourcedictionary, inlines

I am new to this website and new to programming and I have encountered a problem.
I am using Visual Studio 2010, C# WPF Application.

I have this line of code in my program:

```
    TextBlock.Inlines.Add
                  (new Run("text"){ Foreground = Brushes.Blue, FontWeight = FontWeights.ExtraBold });
```

This Line doesn't have any problems, but I have a Resource Dictionary already made with those setters and I'm not sure how I can use it programmatically for each line. I tried something like this but it didn't do anything:

```
TextBlock.Inlines.Add
             (new Run("text") { Style = (Style)this.Resources["bluebold"] });
```

What I think the problem might be is that I'm not calling the Resource dictionary which is called "Styles.xaml" in the code and I am unsure on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it necessary to change it from code? There are lot of approaches as Triggers or StyleSelectors

Here is the code you can use for changing style inside of code:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="StylesFromResourceExample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RunStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Run}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold"/>
    </Style>    </Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="142" />
    <Button Width="100" Height="30" Content="Change" Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows;

namespace StylesFromResourceExample
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("New Text") { Style = (Style)this.FindResource("RunStyle1") });
    }
}
}
```

Let me know, if it si usable for you.

Comment: I have multiple buttons that add different colors of text into a textblock, that's why I need it programatically, as from what I understand, the code that you provided changes all the styles in the textblock to one style.

I tried using 

TextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("text") { Style = (Style)this.FindResource("stylename") });

But It gave me an error: 
'TextBlock' TargetType does not match type of element 'Run'.

Comment: Ok, I changed Style and name of the resource... Try this

Comment: Yep Making the TargetType to Run made it work! Thank you so much! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
ResourceDictionary res = (ResourceDictionary)Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("TreeStyles.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
TestTree.Style = (Style)res["ProjectTree"];
```

[Load Style From Resource File And Set To Elements programmatically](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3eef629d-3d1f-4980-9c4e-860a5f75e96d/load-style-from-resource-file-and-set-to-elements-programmatically?forum=wpf)